# Understanding C# in context of F# for this keyword

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, f#, nancy, c#-to-f#

I am trying Nancy with F#. It pretty cool but I couldn't get it few things in F#. First I ll write down both code.

Here is code of C#

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule()
    {
        this.Get["/"] = (parameters) => View["Index.html"];
    }
}

public class AboutModule : NancyModule
{
    public AboutModule():base("/about")
    {
        this.Get["/"] = (parameters) => "Hello About";
    }
}
```

Here is code of F#

```
type HomeModule() = 
    inherit NancyModule()
    let get = ``base``.Get
    let view = ``base``.View
    do get.["/"] <- fun parameters -> view.["Index.html"] :> obj

type AboutModule() = 
    inherit NancyModule("/about")
    let get = ``base``.Get
    do get.["/"] <- fun parameters -> "Hello About" :> obj
```

Few things I already get, I am putting here just in case someone read this question as reference then s/he will get it.

Do parameter is used as force constructor. It should define after all private or let member of type and before any member of type. As per MSDN.
`base` is equivalent of base in C#. One can use base also but when I did formatting it changed..

So, why `base` is preferable instead of base.
When I tried to called base.View.["Index.html"] within function call it force me to add private member, why? As in C# it just allowed. 
Now here is the thing that I don't get.

In C# I can directly write Get["/"] but in F# I need to write Get.["/"]. Means I have to call another function instead of property constructor.

Even I don't know how "this" use in constructor internally worked in C#, so if someone explain that, it will great...  and if there is any equivalent in F#.

I am also putting nancy code of route builder for reference

```
public class RouteBuilder : IHideObjectMembers
{
    public RouteBuilder(string method, NancyModule parentModule);

    public Func<dynamic, dynamic> this[string path] { set; }
    public Func<dynamic, dynamic> this[string path, Func<NancyContext, bool> condition] { set; }

    protected void AddRoute(string path, Func<NancyContext, bool> condition, Func<dynamic, dynamic> value);
}
```

Please let me know if any further details required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a concrete code snippet, the following example uses `as this` to name the current instance, so that you can refer to it in the constructor (you can use any name for the variable referring to `this`) which directly corresponds to the C# version:

```
type HomeModule() as this = 
  inherit NancyModule()
  do this.Get.["/"] <- fun parameters -> this.View.["Index.html"] :> obj
```

Comment: Thanks @toman. Can you tell me why I have to go for Get.[] instead of direct Get[].

And thanks for this trick. I cut the code even more...

Comment: @kunjee The F# syntax `blah.[idx]` compiles to the exact same IL as the C# syntax `blah[idx]`.

Comment: @JackP. Was just asking to understand the fundamental behind this. Else I don't mind putting . when I am killing lines just because of using F# :)

Answer (score 2):

Some comments:

For the reason you have to use `Get.["/"]` in F#, the problem is the compiler needs to differentiate between an accessors and a function which takes a list as an argument (`["/"] = "/"::[]`)

For the `base` issue, I think you should use `base` without the extra quotes.  You may need to add `as self` to your constructor to be able to use it though, adding the double quotes makes it into a variable name, which doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Can you provide me some code example? And ya, even base converted to variable but it is working perfectly.